# layout_marginLeftPercent only works after lock/unlock (Android Nougat)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-7.0-nougat

As you can see in the image below, my TextViews (Over the question mark) are correctly being positioned vertically by using `app:layout_marginTopPercent="Value"`

But they are not being properly positioned horizontally, using `app:layout_marginLeftPercent="Value"`

What is even stranger is the fact that if I lock my device and then proceed to unlock it while on this screen, the TextView's are displayed 100% correctly.  To top it all off, this only happens on Android 7.0+ devices/emulators.

[image: Issue]

Comment: I wrote this up as a bug for Google.  My problem was marginLeftPercent and widthPercent for the same textview.

Answer (score 0):

Bob Lissner absolutely right. margin Percent (at least marginLeftPercent) is not function properly on Nougat.